# need help to identify this plant, please!

Tags: identification

How do i include pictures?? Impossible without them. If i remember correctly, i planted them from seed two years ago.  Never has bloomed.  This year it has large buds on it and as of now has not opened.  It is about 3 feet tall.  Has very long fragile hairy individual leaves that start right at ground level. If i remember right, i think it was not a perennial for my zone 4 and i protected in winter and it came back.

Comment: Instructions for including photographs are at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Is this tool bar to upload images available on android system?

Comment: It's different on Android phones; see http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/989/22 instead. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: The android app needs the imgur app I think in order to work.  Or just install the imgur app first, upload using that, and then link to the picture.